# USB OTG and ESP32-S2

Tags: esp32, usb, hid

I have an [ESP32-S2-DevKitM-1](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/hw-reference/esp32s2/user-guide-devkitm-1-v1.html) which is supposed to able to act as USB HID device.

But whatever I try using either ESP-IDF or Arduino-IDE, I can't get any data from it.

I ran [this esp-idf example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/peripherals/usb/device/tusb_hid).

I also ran the arduino example.

I [connected](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-reference/peripherals/usb_device.html#hardware-usb-connection) GPIO20/19 to D+/D- of a USB cable.

When I plug in that cable, my host computer logs:

```
usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 93 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 94 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 95 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-6: device not accepting address 95, error -71
usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 96 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-6: device not accepting address 96, error -71
usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The esp-idf example fails to send, because `tud_mounted()` is false, and the arduino-ide example fails on `SendReport(): not ready`.

How can I get the ESP32-S2 to talk USB with my host computer?

Answer (score -1):

This problem went away when I replaced my DIY USB cable connection with an [Adafruit USB-C breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4090).

I checked all the connections of my cable, but somehow it would not work, until I replaced it.